# Полстраны думает или думают?

Tags: согласование

Как следует правильно составить предложение: полстраны думает или полстраны думают?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот какие рекомендации даны в [Справочнике по правописанию и стилистике](https://7lafa.com/book.php?id=121473&page=85) Д. Э. Розенталя.

При подлежащем, выраженном сложным существительным, первую часть которого образует числительное **пол-** (полчаса, полгода, **полстраны** и т. п.), сказуемое обычно ставится в форме единственного числа:
*полчаса пройдёт незаметно, полгода пролетит быстро, **полстраны думает**;*

а в прошедшем времени — в среднем роде, например:
*полчаса прошло незаметно, полгорода участвовало в демонстрации, **полстраны думало**.*

Но если при этих словах имеется определение в форме именительного падежа множественного числа, то и сказуемое ставится во множественном числе, например:
*Первые полчаса прошли незаметно; Остальные полдома уцелели от пожара.*

*И по этим дням, как и я, **полстраны сидит** в кабаках!* (Галич); *Но я не мог ничего ответить, ведь эфир, камеры работают, **полстраны смотрит**...* (Д. Корецкий); *...когда Ельцин был у власти, **полстраны играло** в теннис* (Е. Домарацкая, ‎Е. Дондик-Эделин).

P. S. В составе слова **пол-** — это корень.

Answer (score 0):

Единственное число: думает.

[Москву не **любит полстраны**](https://vm.ru/news/653660.html)

---

[Зачем России Олимпиада в Сочи, ядерное оружие, амбиции супердержавы? Когда **полстраны думает**, чем кормить детей, нужен ли второй ребёнок в семье, а относительное благополучие страны держится на экспорте нефти и газа.](http://blog.da-medvedev.ru/theme/22?page=257)

---

[**Полстраны думает**, что это – температура! Хотя непонятно, чего? Ночью будет во дворе или сейчас в помещении? Или внутри телевизора? А может, экран перегрелся?](https://www.mk.ru/blogs/blog-mihaila-zadornova-page24.html)